# Order of Vector elements for C++

Tags: c++, vector

The following piece of c++ code gives

```
int main()
{
    vector <int> myvect(3,0);
    vector <int> :: iterator it;
    it = myvect.begin();
    myvect.insert(it,200);
    myvect.insert(it+5,400);         //Not sure what 5 makes the difference here
    cout << myvect[0] << endl << myvect[1];
}
```

Output :

```
200
400
```

And the same code with minor changes gives

```
int main()
{
    vector <int> myvect(3,0);
    vector <int> :: iterator it;
    it = myvect.begin();
    myvect.insert(it,200);
    myvect.insert(it+4,400);         //Not sure what 4 makes the difference here
    cout << myvect[0] << endl << myvect[1];
}
```

Output:

```
400
200
```

Can someone tell me why adding 4 or 5 to the iterator changes the order of elements?

Thanks

Comment: See [tag:undefined-behavior] and the various links there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program has **Undefined Behavior**.

You are creating a vector of 3 elements (all initialized to 0), and you are inserting elements at position `v.begin() + 5`, which is beyond the end of the vector.

Moreover, you are using an iterator (`it)` after inserting an element *before* the position `it` points to. According to Paragraph 23.3.6.5/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references **before the insertion point** remain valid. [...]

Therefore, iterator `it` itself is not guaranteed to be valid after the statement `myvect.insert(it, 200)`, and using it in the next instruction (`myvect.insert(it + 4, 400)`) is again Undefined Behavior.

You cannot expect anything of a program with Undefined Behavior. It may crash, give you bizarre results, or (in the worst case) behave just as you would expect.

Comment: It also uses an iterator after inserting an element before it, which invalidates the iterator. So the second example is UB as well.

Answer (score 1):

The member function `vector::insert(const_iterator, const value_type&)` requires a valid iterator that refers to the vector but `it+4` and `it+5` are not valid iterators.

Before the first insertion, `it+3` is a valid (non-dereferencable) iterator, pointing just past-the-end of the vector sequence, but `it+4` is invalid.  After the insertion `it` *might* get invalidated, in which case no expression using `it` is valid, certainly not `it+5` because the sequence only has four elements at that point.

The code would be valid if changed like so:

```
it = myvect.begin();
myvect.insert(it,200);
it = myvect.begin();     // make it valid again
myvect.insert(it+4,400);
```

Comment: No, not if the first insertion causes the vector to reallocate, because that would make `it` invalid